# String or binary data would be truncated exception?

Tags: .net, sqlexception

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO sms_sentmessages(Mobilefrom,Mobileto,Message,senddate) VALUES('" + str.Substring(0, str.Length - 4).ToString() + "','" + number + "','" + txtmessage.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim() + "',getdate())", con);
                                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str.Substring(0, str.Length - 4)
```

and/ or

```
txtmessage.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim()
```

are too large to fit with the column you're trying to insert into.

Answer (score 2):

Well, presumably you're trying to insert a value into the table and it exceeds the length for the column. You should validate the data before you try to execute the SQL insert.

However, you should *also* use a parameterized query - currently your code is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. See the [Bobby Tables site](http://bobby-tables.com/) for more information. Basically, parameterized SQL allows you to keep the *code* (SQL) separate from the data (parameters), making your code clearer and preventing SQL injection attacks (assuming you're not *also* using dynamic SQL).

(Finally, it's not clear why you're calling `ToString()` on the result of a `Substring` call...)

Answer (score 0):

Your data (or possibly a trigger) is too big to fit into the column you are trying to store it.

At least, that's my best guess.