# .NET/sql exception on site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, sqlexception

yesterday a client called and reported a problem while trying to access our website. He can open the index page but then every article on the page throws and sql exception and he get's a yellow page (yellow page of death)
**Exception type: SqlException 
Exception message: String or binary data would be truncated.**
Now, I checked all blocking's on the server and on IIS and neither of them is blocking him or preventing from accessing page content. I tried logging in with his credentials and everything works fine, he also can log in from his home PC but just cant from his company network/PC.
I checked with his Internet Service Provider and they also allow all traffic, there are no proxy's or limitations for certain addresses or networks. Any idea what causes that?
Another thing I need to check today is...there was one version of mozilla/chrome which, if you  select the autocomplete value for the username, it added some invisible chars and you had to retype for ex. the username again and mustn't select it from the textbox as autocomplete.

Edit: The client doesn't need to logged in, he just cant open any article on the site, whether authenticated or not. But every article he is trying to open I can, like the rest of  out client's

Comment: have alook to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872300/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-exception

Comment: @RahulRJ I now that the error text indicates something like that but ...
What could it be, I mean i now what I am storing...the user-agent, ip address, referrer and the site he's accessing. All fields are big enough...how could I simulate his expirience on the site? Is there any chance that something may be wrong on his site/network...?

Answer (score 0):

[String or binary data would be truncated](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/string-or-binary-data-truncated/)

Your application is trying to insert something in the database and the text writen is larger than the column size defined in your database.

Comment: but how come it doesn't try to insert that value when I log in with the client's credentials from my network, on my PC? I mean, I forgot to mention that...he doesn't need to log in, he just cant open any article on the site, whether authenticated or not.

Comment: I now that the error text indicates something like that but ...
What could it be, I mean i now what I am storing...the user-agent, ip address, referrer and the site he's accessing. All fields are big enough...how could I simulate his expirience on the site? Is there any chance that something may be wrong on his site/network...?

Comment: If you can't debug and can't reproduce the proble in your environment, perhaps you can use SQL Server Profiler to trace the SQL sentences and have an idea of where is the problem.